# How in Java to export data from the entire database?

Tags: java, sql, xml, database

There is a code that exports the data from the database in xml.

```
    public class DataExtractor{

   private final String login, passwd, host;

   public DataExtractor(String login, String passwd, String host){
       this.login = login;
       this.passwd = passwd;
       this.host = host;
   }

   public String getTableData(String tableName) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
       Connection con = null;
       Statement st = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///" + host, login, passwd);

           st = con.createStatement();
           rs = st.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);

           ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
           int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

           StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("<table>\n");

           int num = 1;
           while (rs.next()) {
               b.append("<row>");
               b.append("<num>").append(num++).append("</num>");
               for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
                   String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                   b.append('<').append(columnName).append('>');
                   b.append(rs.getObject(i));
                   b.append("</").append(columnName).append('>');
               }
               b.append("</row>\n");
           }
           b.append("</table>");
           return b.toString();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw e;
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           throw e;
       } finally {
           if (rs != null)
               try {
                   rs.close();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
               }
           if (st != null)
               try {
                   st.close();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
               }
           if (con != null)
               try {
                   con.close();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
               }
       }
   }
}
```

But this class of exports only the data from a given table, how to make sure that the data exported from the entire database (ie, all tables), and not from a particular table. That is, should get the output XML file types:

```
  <database>
      <table1>
             <id> </ id>
             <Name> </ Name>
                           ...
       </ table1>

        <table2>
               ...
       </ table2>


</ database>
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at your DBMS' documentation. Most provide a built-in export feature - be it in CVS, XML or binary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
show tables
```

then loop over the tables and call your method `getTableData()`

You might want to consider getting the columns names as well:
`SHOW columns FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: [dbsql2xml](http://dbsql2xml.sourceforge.net/) is Java tool (class) for transformation (export, convert) relational database into hierarchical XML. It requires JRE 5.0, JDBC and SQL DBMS. "dbsql2xml" uses XML document for mapping database tables and columns into elements of tree XML

Answer (score 0):

[Dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/faq.html#extract) is a well established tool for manipulating database data as XML.

Another tool useful for extracting related subsets of data from a database is [jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/). It also supports the dbunit XML format.